# XtraReport DocumentViewer set report document programmatically

Tags: winforms, xtrareport

I am using DevXpress 14.
I want to use only one form name "FrmViewer" which contain DocumentVier to load any report I want.
This is the code, the datasource is not null (debugged), but the message is "The document contain no page". I think I missed some method of the documentViewer to start print

```
public FrmViewer(PhieuNhap pn)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RptPhieuNhap rpt = new RptPhieuNhap();
            rpt.DataSource = pn.ChiTietPhieuNhap;
            rpt.nhacungcap.Value = pn.NhaCungCap.TenCC;
            rpt.sophieu.Value = pn.SoPhieu;    
            documentViewer1.PrintingSystem = rpt.PrintingSystem;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to call rpt.CreateDocument();

See here for more details:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q528191